# Number of views in discussion board

Tags: list-view, 2016, discussion-board

how can show the number of views for each item in a discussion board

I need to show the number of views as a new column in a discussion board

```
subject || likes  ||   views

test.        5        200

testz.       4        10
```

any thoughts?